# Horizontal Bootstrap buttons stacking twice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to understand this behavior:

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYxvOV)

```
<div class="container-fluid buy-now">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="buy-now-button" >BUY NOW FOR $400</button>

                     <button id="make-an-offer-button" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">MAKE AN OFFER</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Basically, the buttons stay next to each other until I get to about 1244px width when they stack on top of each other. Then, they go BACK to horizontal at about 768px. But then, at about 620px width, they go to stacked again.

Why is there such a "jumpy" behavior at seemingly random screen resolutions? According to the definitions I've set, these buttons should stay next to each other right until 768px (and below), when they go back to stacked mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `sm` classes in the third line with `xs` so that it applies to *all* sizes:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
```

This will result in only one horizontal/vertical break.

Here it is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaMxPY

--

Second solution:

Erase `col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6` from that tag, resulting in

```
<div class="text-center">
```

This will center the buttons and only stack them when the screen becomes too narrow to have them side by side.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaMxPY

--

Or use a smaller offset and a wider container class:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 text-center">
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxZBbx

--

And you can make the buttons smaller, by applying a different class to them (`btn-sm` instead of `btn-lg`) and changing their font-sizes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpMjyx

Comment: Thanks, but 768px seems to be too "high" for buttons to start stacking at, is there a way to lower the threshold, say at 400-500px, or up until the point it's no longer possible for those 2 to be one next to each other?

Comment: Well, you can erase those classes (offset and col-6) completely and only leave the text centering - I'll add that to my answer in a minute